# design pattern / different approach for building different objects

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a piece of code that I need to continue development on.
Part of it is a class which has a lot of different elements which are instantiated when the class is built.
Theoretically, there can be more classes in the future to built which will result in another new line to be added.
Right now there are 17 lines of new up code.
I'm trying to think of a better way to do it instead of the current one of just adding a new line for creating a new (and different) object

As an example:

```
var RTFStorage = new StorageFormat(container, Types.RTF, new RTFOptions());
var PDFStorageFormat = new StorageFormat(container, Types.PDF, new PDFOptions());
```

The calls are newing up the same object but with different params. (the above code is just an exmaple.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: You should add some more details, like how these StorageFormat classes are used. Do you always need all of them, or you only need one depending on some parameters?

Comment: Seems like the `Types` and the `Options` relate to each other. I'm *guessing* the Options inherit the same base type (or implement the same interface). So you might want to have a factory, where you get a new `Options` based on the `Types`. And then you can also have a factory to get instances of `StorageFormat` based on the `Types`, but in the end you will still have something like `var RTFStorage = factory.Create(Types.RTF); var PDFStorageFormat = factory.Create(Types.PDF); [...]`. You could even put them in a `Dictionary<Types, StorageFormat>`. But I doubt it would get much "nicer"...

Comment: This looks like a place where you could use Dependency Injection. Then you could potentially modify the list of supported formats from an external configuration file without needing to recompile your code. Just inject an array of IOptions classes, and make sure each IOptions implementations has a field from which you can retrieve the corresponding Types value. Better yet, use DI to do everything and build the array of StorageFormat objects for you.

Comment: The DI sounds interesting even though it's a typescript project (in relation to the configuration file). I'll give it a try.